# pass variable from method to actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am new to Java and I try to write a simple code. I faced a problem with passing button00 to ActionListener, so I can program the buttons to do smth. I understand that I need to somehow access the button00 in the createandshowgui () but I don't know how. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

```
package gui;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;



public class gui_tryout extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public int count;
public void menuoption() {

    JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar ();
    JMenu menufile = new JMenu ("File");
    menufile.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F); 
    // ^ hot key. if you press ALT+F => File will pop up
    menu.add(menufile);
    JMenu menustats = new JMenu ("Stats");
    menu.add(menustats);
    menustats. setMnemonic (KeyEvent.VK_D);
    setJMenuBar(menu);
    JMenuItem menu_file_new = new JMenuItem ("New");
    menu_file_new.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
    menufile.add(menu_file_new);
    JMenuItem score_display = new JMenuItem("Score");
    menustats.add(score_display);
}



private static void createandshowgui(){

     gui_tryout newframe = new gui_tryout ();
     newframe.setSize(400, 300);
     newframe.setLayout (new GridLayout (3,3));
     newframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     newframe.setVisible(true);

    //Adding Grid to the Window
     JButton button00 = new JButton (" "); //0 0 
     newframe.add(button00);
     JButton button01 = new JButton (" "); //0 1 
     newframe.add(button01);
     JButton button02 = new JButton (" "); //0 2    
     newframe.add(button02);
     JButton button10 = new JButton (" "); //1 0
     newframe.add(button10);
     JButton button11 = new JButton (" "); //1 1
     newframe.add(button11);
     JButton button12 = new JButton (" "); //1 2
     newframe.add(button12);
     JButton button20 = new JButton (" "); //2 0
     newframe.add(button20);
     JButton button21 = new JButton (" "); //2 1
     newframe.add(button21);
     JButton button22 = new JButton (" "); //2 2
     newframe.add(button22);

     newframe.menuoption(); //adding menu part to the code
} 

 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    count ++;

    //button00.addActionListener(this);

    //whose turn is it?
    if (count ==1 || count == 3 || count == 5 || count == 7 || count == 9){ 
        //display X
    }
        else if (count == 2 || count == 4 || count == 6 || count == 8)
    {
        //display O
    }

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable (){
         public void run() {
             createandshowgui();
          }
 });
 }
 }
```

Comment: Why would you want to access `button00` in the actionPerformed() method? Also, please respect the Java naming conventions. Classes are WrittenLikeThat. Methods and variables are writtenLikeThat.

Comment: Abdul Fatir : I have not set the ActionListener yet. what I want to do is smth like this: button00.addActionListener(this);. I can do this only in ActionPerformed part but  I cannot access button00 from ActionPerformed function.

Comment: That's precisely the place where you can't do it. Your actionPerformed() method will never be called if the action listener hasn't been added to any button yet.

Answer (score 1):

Make your Button an `instance variable`. Then you can access it in other class methods. Currently it is a local variable and it's scope is limited to that method.

```
public class gui_tryout extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
   private Button button00 = new JButton (" ");
   // rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set any action listener to any button, use:

```
 JButton button00 = new JButton (" "); //0 0 
 newframe.add(button00);
 button00.addActionListener(newframe);//Your JFrame implements ActionListener
```

Also, how you are doing it is not the right approach. You need to make the components and should initialize them in the constructor of your class which extends JFrame.